# Reading one additional row of excel file with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Using Apache POI, I am trying to read an excel file. The file has 1000 rows and 1 column. With this code:

```
    XSSFSheet ws = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator< Row > rowIt = ws.iterator();
    XSSFRow row;
    int i = 0;
    while ( rowIt.hasNext() ) {
      row = (XSSFRow) rowIt.next();
      Iterator< Cell > cellIt = row.cellIterator();
      while ( cellIt.hasNext() ) {
        Cell cell = cellIt.next();
        my_array[ i ] = cell.getStringCellValue();
      }
      ++i;
    }
```

It seems that it reads 1001 rows and since the last row is "", my_array get invalid string. Is there any way to fix that? I expect `rowIt.hasNext()` is responsible for that but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file has 1000 rows and 1 column : you must specify what column you are reading.
>   here an exemple that specify column with this excel file:

[image: exemple excel file]

```
public class TestLecture {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    List<String> mys_list= new ArrayList<String>();
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xlsx"));

    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);

    //Get first sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet ws = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
    Iterator<Row> rowIt = ws.iterator();


     while (rowIt.hasNext()) {

         Row row = rowIt.next();
         Iterator<Cell> cellIt = row.iterator();

         while (cellIt.hasNext()) {

             Cell cell = cellIt.next();
             int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
             switch (columnIndex) {
             case 2:

                 mys_list.add(cell.getStringCellValue());

                 break;


             }

         }


     }

     System.out.println(mys_list.size());
     for(String g :mys_list){
         System.out.println(g);
     }



}
```

}